# Excel VBA AutoFilter on user selection run-time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel 2010 workbook containing 2 sheets ("Contents" and "Folders").

The purpose of this workbook is to track different pieces of work by supplier or reference number, with a front-end (the Contents page) that is simple to use, consisting only of buttons and a search box (Which isn't actually a separate box, but simply the contents of cell J8 of the Contents sheet (hereafter referred to as J8) as typed by the user.

The buttons will filter by supplier type (and work perfectly fine) but it's the user selection that I'm having trouble with.

My code for this macro is:

```
    Sub Find_Click()
    Dim userSelect As String
    userSelect = "*" & Range("J8") & "*"
    Sheets("Folders").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$5000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria:=userSelect, Operator:=x1And
    End Sub
```

When the 'Find' button is pressed, this should read J8, then select the Folders sheet and filter the result to show every entry in column B that contains the text in J8.

This was working fine.  However, now when I try to use this macro I get a 1004 run-time error with the 'Application-defined or object-defined error' message.

Can anyone please help?

EDIT:

The Contains buttons that have macros assigned that follow this format:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheets("Folders").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
    "Criteria"
    Set r = Range(Range("A3"), Range("A3").End(xlDown))
j = WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
'MsgBox j
If j = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There is currently no work relating to Criteria"
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
    Sheets("Contents").Select
End If
End Sub
```

There is also a resest button that clears a filter and returns to the Contents sheet:

```
Sub Reset_Click()
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Sheets("Contents").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you'll need to activate a cell inside the range in which you are going to use the `AutoFilter`.

Further more, when you are trying to use AutoFilter with wildcards (`*` or `?`) or math test, you'll need to add an `=` at the start of your criteria string, so

```
userSelect = "=*" & Range("J8") & "*"
```

Then, it is not `Criteria`, but `Criteria1` and `Criteria2` if you use a second one! So you don't need an `Operator` in this case.

And finally with  `ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$5000").AutoFilter Field:=2`, you are asking the code to filter on the second column of a range where there is only one column!

So if you want to filter on col B, just change `Field:=2` to `Field:=1`

---

Here is the working code :

```
Sub Find_Click()
Dim userSelect As String
Dim wS as Worksheet
userSelect = "=*" & Range("J8") & "*"
Set wS = Sheets("Folders")
wS.Activate
wS.Range("B1").Activate
If Not wS.AutoFilterMode Then wS.AutoFilterMode = True
wS.Range("$B$1:$B$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=userSelect
End Sub
```

And you also had a typo in `xlAnd`, it was `x1And` ;)

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I'm not sure how the typo got there when it was copied and pasted from the VBA editor and it's correct there...  Weird!

I've added the ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Activate line and now I'm getting run-time error 424 Object Required.

The thing I don't understand is why it worked perfectly fine for a time, and then randomly decided to stop!

Comment: Actually, that was me being an idiot (ActivateSheet is not the same as ActiveSheet, strangely enough...)

I'm still getting the 1004 though.

Comment: @theamazingmrg : On which line do you get which error?

Comment: Hi,

It's ActiveSheet.Range("$B$3:$B$5000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria:=userSelect, Operator:=x1And that's causing the problem.

Comment: @theamazingmrg : you still got a `1` instead of an `l`/`L` in what you commented, did you correct that already?

Comment: I hadn't (I thought you meant the typo was the other way round!).  I've changed it now but it hasn't helped.

Comment: @theamazingmrg : Change `Criteria` to `Criteria1` and get rid of the `Operator` part as you only have one criteria

Comment: Making those changes results in the following error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range Class

Comment: @theamazingmrg : Are you trying to add a new criteria upon another one that is already set? You could test the `AutoFilterMode`, edit incoming

Comment: I don't think I'm trying to add any other criteria.  The other buttons on the page filter column A by a fixed value and works fine.  Then, to return to the Contents page I have set up a button that resets all filters on the page, so the 'Find' macro should only ever be using the one criteria, which is set when the 'Find' button is pressed.

Comment: @theamazingmrg : I'm so blind myself... You missed the `=` in your criteria string to make it work, try the edit! ;)

Comment: do you mean in the If wS.AutoFilterMode... statement?  And should that be set to If wS.AutoFilterMode = False...?

Comment: @theamazingmrg : No, here `userSelect = "=*" & Range("J8") & "*"` test the edit! ;)

Comment: Still nothing :(

I just don't understand why it doesn't like what should be a simple snippet of code!

Comment: @theamazingmrg : Strange... Which error and at which line? Try to add `Debug.print userSelect` to see if it is indeed what you expect...

Comment: It's still the 1004 Autofilter method of Range class failed error message in the wS.Range("$B$1:$B$5000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=userSelect line

Comment: @theamazingmrg : what if you try `wS.Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=userSelect`

Comment: @theamazingmrg : I just understood!!!! You are asking the code to filter on the second column of a range where there is only one column!!! So if you want to filter on col B, just change `Field:=2` to `Field:=1`

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you so much!!!  It's typical that it would be something so simple (and I'm not sure why it originally worked either if that was the problem!) but it's working now so I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, the problem ended up being in the line:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$5000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=userSelect
```

As the code was filtering only column B, the Field value needed to be set to '1' instead of my original '2'

Thanks to @R3uK for his invaluable help!

Comment: Thx mate, I can't believe I did't see it earlier! ;) I'll edit my answer to reflect what we changed from your initial code! Could you accept it? Take a minute to take the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour