# Multiple Autofilter criteria (Array) Run-Time error 1004

Tags: arrays, excel, runtime-error, vba

General Goal: Applying multiple filters through a sheet of raw data, then pasting the rows for the respective filters into different sheets.

Assuming the raw data sheet has data from columns A:J, Column A has different variables, e.g. LVROA. (There are actually about 27 unique variables but I am more interested in the logic and this one is giving me issues). Please note, I also need to filter to exclude building 3 ("<>03*") from column F (field6) and use a separate worksheet for that building's infos.

So far I have used rather simplistic/pragmatic coding to do the filtering and pasting for me, row 1 is the different headers:

```
Public Sub LVROA ()
   Sheets("Raw Data Amendment").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="LVROA"
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Autofilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="<>03*"
   Range("A1:J4000").Copy 'J4000 randomly set to ensure it includes all data)
   Sheets("LVROA").Select
   ActiveSheet.paste
 End Sub

Public Sub LVROA_3()
   Sheets("Raw Data Amendment").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="LVROA"
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Autofilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="03*"
   Range("A1:J4000").Copy
   Sheets("LVROA_3").Select
   ActiveSheet.paste
 End Sub
```

Now I need to additionally separate LVROA by buildings 7,9, and 20 ("07*","09*","20*"). These all go on one sheet, but this also means excluding them from the initial LVROA worksheet, so in total my filter there needs to exclude ("<>03*","<>07*","<>09*","<>20*"). This is where I get an error.

I tried the following without success:

```
Public Sub LVROA ()
   Sheets("Raw Data Amendment").Select
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Autofilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="LVROA"
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").Autofilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("<>03*", _
   "<>07*","<>09*","<>20*"), _
   Operator:=xlFilterValues
   Range("A1:J4000").Copy
   Sheets("LVROA").Select
   ActiveSheet.paste
 End Sub
```

Run-time error '1004' - AutoFilter method of Range Class Failed, highlighted are the Operator line and the line with the Array for buildings to exclude.

I found a similar run-time error in this thread **[VBA Autofilter With Multiple Criteria Using Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135144/vba-autofilter-with-multiple-criteria-using-variables)**, but I have declared the field (6) so I don't think that's the issue. This one also doesn't seem to answer my problem **[Excel VBA AutoFilter on user selection run-time error 1004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961134/excel-vba-autofilter-on-user-selection-run-time-error-1004)**

Once I figure out how to exclude these buildings, I should be easily be able to figure out how to filter only for them for their worksheet.

Any help is appreciated, ideally I would like to significantly shorten all this and make it more proficient via a loop. But looping it would probably still give me the same issue.

Comment: Check your syntax code: you have errors on the lines `Criteria:=1:="LVROA"` , `Criteria1:=:="LVROA"` and `Criteria1:=:="LVROA"`.

Comment: Thanks for the note, sorry about that. This was just accidental errors when re-writing the code for this thread. (I didn't copy/paste it)

I assume if that was the main issue the code couldn't run paste that line, but in my excel it does. The actual error comes in the Array filter line and the operator line. Maybe it would help if attach a sample of the excel?

Comment: Try `Operator:=xlAnd` Instead of `Operator:=xlFilterValues`.