# Unable to filter using InputBox in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VBA code to filter Date and a subject name to perform some analysis. The date filtering is working all fine but I am not able to filter the subject name using an InputBox. I am assigning the the InputBox to an Object a and calling it in the filter but it gives me Run-time Error 1004, Application defined or Object Defined error.

Here is my code. Could anybody please help me with resolving the issue? I am facing error with the Subject Name filtering.

```
Sub Quality_Check()
'
' Quality_Check Macro
'

'
    Dim dte As Date
    Dim a As String
    Dim score As Integer
    mBox = InputBox("Enter a date")

If IsDate(mBox) Then
dte = CDate(mBox)
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AB" & Lastrow).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & dte, _
                                          Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & dte + 1
    
    End If
    a = InputBox("Enter the Subject Name")
    With Sheets("Raw Data")
    .Range("A1").Select
    .Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    .Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    
    End With
    
    Selection.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria:=a
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Filtered").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `Criteria1` not `Criteria`

```
Selection.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=a
```

You can refer to the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961134/excel-vba-autofilter-on-user-selection-run-time-error-1004)